# parsing XML using linq to xml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I want to parse some large XML file using linq to XML but I don't know how exactly can I do this.
I want to read all `<name>` tag that come after `<dac>` tag. I must mentioned I have many `<name>` tag in XMl file I just want to read that one come after `<dac>`. How can I do this using linq to xml?

Here is a simple sample of my XML file:
I want the code return me such value: `(SSS, HHH, HHH Panel)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<installationTree>
  <folder>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Company</name>
    <full-path>Door List / Company</full-path>
    <nodes>
      <controller>
        <id>9</id>
        <name>9016 Panel</name>
        <description/>        
        <full-path>Door List / Company / 9016 Panel</full-path>
        <nodes>
          <dac>
            <isOneDoorController>false</isOneDoorController>
            <id>9</id>
            <name>SSS</name>
            <description/>
            <address>1</address>
            <active>true</active>
            <externalId>ID:9_20111123_121106</externalId>
            <mode>standard</mode>    

            <doorCodes/>
            <full-path>Door List / Company / 9016 Panel / SSS</full-path>
            <nodes/>
          </dac>
          <dac>
            <isOneDoorController>false</isOneDoorController>
            <id>10</id>
            <name>HHH</name>
            <description/>
            <address>2</address>
            <active>true</active>

            <doorCodes/>
            <full-path>Door List / Company / 9016 Panel / HHH</full-path>
            <nodes/>
          </dac>
        </nodes>
      </controller>
      <oneDoorController>
        <id>8</id>
        <name>HHH Panel</name>
        <description/>
        <serialnumber>00:06:8e:30:24:24</serialnumber>
        <timezone>Iran</timezone>
        <active>true</active>
        <docUpdater/>
        <nodes>
          <dac>
            <isOneDoorController>true</isOneDoorController>
            <id>8</id>
            <name>HHH Panel</name>
            <description/>
            <address>1</address>
            <active>false</active>            
            <doorCodes/>
          </dac>
          <full-path>Door List / Company / HHH Panel</full-path>
          <nodes/>
        </nodes>
      </oneDoorController>
    </nodes>
  </folder>
</installationTree>
```

Comment: Do you want the `name` tags *after* or *inside* the `dac` tags?

Comment: You posted invalid XML. Please correct it.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth the first name tags in the block of dac tags

Comment: @AVD I just copy some part of my entire XML to show the structure, I can not copy all of it because it has a large size.

Comment: @Am1rr3 : post a much shorter and valid piece of XML and specify the desired outcome.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I fix it and specify what is my desire result

Comment: @AVD I post some correct format of my XML file now.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA - All credit goes to Henk Holterman and you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the XML document and write the statement suggested by `@Henk Holterman`.

```
string file = @"c:\file.xml";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
var names= doc.Root.Descendants("dac").Elements("name");

foreach (var t in names)
   Console.WriteLine(t.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
 var names = doc.Root.Descendants("dac").Elements("name");
```

This assumes each `<dac>` contains at most 1 `<name>` element.